# Storyboard to a nib

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, storyboard, nib

I have an `RSS` parser in a `UITableView` that pushes to the detail view when one of the rows is selected. I had it working fine in the old UI format of using `Nib` files, but I wanted to transfer everything to `UIStoryboard`. I learned that `UIStoryboards` and `nibs` were compatible, so I decided I would keep the same code, but put the `UITableView` in the `UIStoryboard` and have the detail view be its own nib. I linked everything up and it should be working, and its not giving me any errors, but its not. Is there anything that I missed, or are storyboards and nibs not compatible at all.

**Edit:**

```
- (id)initWithItem:(NSDictionary *)theItem {
    if (self == [super initWithNibName:@"RssDetailController" bundle:nil]) {
        self.item = theItem;
        self.title = [item objectForKey:@"title"];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: "It's not working" isn't a helpful description of your problem. But just as a thought I believe the initializer that the storyboard calls is `initWithCoder:`.

Comment: The view just isnt pushing to the detailviewcontroller. I just wanted to know if there was anything that needs to be put in when transferring the view from a storyboard to a nib.

Comment: Show the code where you are pushing your detail view controller.

Comment: This is not the push code. This is the initialization in RssDetailController. The push should be called from table view upon selecting a row. Did you hook up the table view in storyboard with its respective class?

Answer (score 1):

Are you pushing from a `UIViewController` in `UIStoryboard` to a `NIB` file?

If so check out [this sample project](https://github.com/LuAndreCast/ObjectiveC_Projects/tree/master/scrollView/scrollViewFromStoryBoard_And_XIB_File) that pushes from storyboard to a `NIB`:

```
// in a navigation controller

// to load/push to new controller use this code

// this will be next screen
DetailsViewController *detailsViewController = [[DetailsViewController alloc ]init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailsViewController animated:YES];


// to go back or pop controller use this
// now it will send back to parent screen
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```